# How to display sharepreferences item in Listview android

Tags: android

I just want to retrieve the data that save from sharedpreferences and display it in listview. Currently I just only manage to display the data with only one line in my SecondActivity. What I want is to display those data separately in listview, is there any expert how to solve this thanks in advance

[image: Retrieving data from sharedpref]

> My shared preferences

[image: My shared preferences]

> MainActivity to save sharedpref

```
public void save_append_list_tosharefpref (String data){

    List<String> favorites = new ArrayList<String>();
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = settings.edit();

    Map<String, ?> allPrefs = settings.getAll(); //my existing sharedPreference
    Set<String> set = allPrefs.keySet();

    if (allPrefs.toString() =="{}" || allPrefs.toString() =="[]"){
        favorites.add(data);
    }
    else {
        for(String s : set){
            favorites.add(data);
            favorites.add(allPrefs.get(s).toString());
            Log.d(TAG,"bagona"+allPrefs.get(s).toString());
        }

    }
    editor.putString(FAVORITES, favorites.toString());
    editor.commit();
}
```

> SecondActivity

```
public void view_from_shared_preferences(){
    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    settings =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    editor = settings.edit();

    Map<String, ?> allPrefs = settings.getAll(); //your sharedPreference
    Set<String> set = allPrefs.keySet();

    for(String s : set){
        Log.d(TAG,"This is all data "+allPrefs.get(s).toString());

        String rep =allPrefs.get(s).toString();
        String seps = rep.replace("]", "");
        String seps1 = seps.replace("[", "");
        Log.d(TAG,"final data "+seps1);
        arrayAdapter.add(seps1);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you Use `putStringSet`instead of  `putString`

---

NOTE: required api level 11

---

Reference of how to use `putStringSet` is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/7057858/12676247

Answer (score 0):

After getting string with , use

```
List<String> elephantList = Arrays.asList(str.split(","));
```

to get ArrayList and use that to set listview

Comment: thanks for response , it is tricky idea, but can you explain the details?. I tried it but it always return the same output

Comment: may be arrayAdapter.addAll(elephantList );

Comment: also i would suggest you to use sqlite to save data , sharedprefs are for key value pair type data storage.